# Why isn't my container occupying all available space in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In the markup below, I have the Label in a Scrollviewer. Ideally I don't want to have the DockPanel there but its in there for testing (it didn't solve the issue).

I want the Scrollviewer to fill remaining space (putting the "Send Email" button at the bottom of the column).

Doesn't seem to matter what I do, I can't get the darn thing to do it...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Campaigns}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCampaign}"
                  Text="Select a Campaign"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Emails}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Subject"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmail}"
                  Text="Select an Email"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}"
                  Text="Select a Contact Group"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding LoadContactsCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedGroup}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                ToolTip="Refresh the current list of contacts." Content="Load Contacts"/>
        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Label Content="{Binding SendStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding SendEmailsCommand}" Content="Send Emails"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use StackPanel if you want some element to stretch vertically. StackPanel can offer infinite vertical space for arrange, but it doesn't make sense to stretch to infinity so minimal possible size is used.

use Grid with multiple RowDefinitions instead and place stretching element in a row with `Height="*"`:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Campaigns}" Grid.Row="0"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCampaign}"
              Text="Select a Campaign"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Emails}"  Grid.Row="1"
              DisplayMemberPath="Subject"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmail}"
              Text="Select an Email"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"  Grid.Row="2"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}"
              Text="Select a Contact Group"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding LoadContactsCommand}" Grid.Row="3"
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedGroup}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            ToolTip="Refresh the current list of contacts." Content="Load Contacts"/>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Label Content="{Binding SendStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Button Grid.Row="5" Command="{Binding SendEmailsCommand}" Content="Send Emails"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :) Not sure why I didn't think of it but this actually even looks better than the StackPanel did.